# How to use www in editor script

Tags: unity-game-engine

I know how to use www in a runtime script, but is there any way to use www in a editor script?

```c#
    IEnumerator Download()
    {
        WWW www = new WWW (url);
        yield return www;
        Debug.Log (www.text);
    }
```

Or is there any way to download file from the Internet in a editor script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A year late, but I am running into this issue too. Since you can't call `StartCoroutine` in the Unity3d editor context, you need to either use a custom manager like this: https://gist.github.com/benblo/10732554

Alternatively, you can manually deal with the `IEnumerator` like this:

```c#
IEnumerator enumerator = Download();

// Current points to null here, so move it forward
enumerator.MoveNext();

// This blocks, but you can always use a thread
while ( ! ((WWW)(enumerator.Current)).isDone );

// This triggers your 'Debug.Log(www.text)'
enumerator.MoveNext();
```

Hopefully this helps.